# DB2/400 field with CCSID 1208 (UTF-8) and oledbtype issue

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, db2, oledbconnection

I have a table in AS/400 DB2 table:

```
SCDSC VARCHAR(120) CCSID 1208 DEFAULT NULL ,
```

CCSID 1208 implies UTF-8.

In my c# code this is the definition that works.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("scdsc", OleDbType.VarChar  , 120);
```

i have tried also with VarWChar type:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("scdsc", OleDbType.VarWChar  , 120);
```

The problem is that the maximum that this field gets is 60 characters. I cant make it work with 60 characters length in the field.

I find it odd that i need to double the true length of my fields (i did it for all my string fields) in order to make it work.

**UPDATE:** Correct implementation is to define the fields in DB as nvarchar and oledbtype as varWchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the column as nvarchar. You are defining it varchar 120, which means it can only hold 120 bytes, instead of the needed 240.

The varchar type is for non-unicode, 1byte=1character strings.

Comment: So it has to be VarWChar 60 in c#, and in DB2? varchar(6) doesnt work. Maybe nvarchar(60)?

Comment: @e4rthdog no I mean, you defined your column with varchar(120), where as it should have been varwchar(120)...

Comment: I got it, but in the first place i needed space for a field for 60 chars.....So in order to be able to hold 60 chars i have to define varWchar(60) and in DB2 nvarchar(60)? (now i have varchar not nvarchar)

Comment: @e4rthdog Ah, if you need 60 unicode characters, then define the field as nvarchar(60), not varchar(60).